# Serial 80s back-page comic "The Tree That Bends"

Tags: story-identification

Wondering if you can help me find a comic serial that may have ran in the back of a young adult or sci-fi magazine in the late 80s/early 90s:

I can't remember the name, but it was similar in tone to the "Pool of Fire" Tripod stuff Boys' Life published around that time, but I remember it being black + white, and the story revolved around an ant-like alien civilization. I feel like the name may have been "The Tree That Doesn't Bend, Breaks" or "The Tree That Bends".

Does that sound familiar at all?

Comment: Did it involve humans interacting with the civilization, or just the civilization itself?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Good question... I think humans interacting with them? I remember the story revolved around some faction trying to change the civilization and it being very rigid. Eventually change was not allowed and there was some sort of collapse as a result and in maybe the last issue one of the characters says to another "...the tree that doesn't bend, breaks."